# Release build says SQL is invalid. Is this a configuration issue?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using the following code and I get this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '??]?j?X?0' at line 1

My code is as follows this works perfectly in the debug build

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//#define CPPCONN_PUBLIC_FUNC
/* MySQL Connector/C++ specific headers */
#include <driver.h>
#include <connection.h>
#include <statement.h>
#include <prepared_statement.h>
#include <resultset.h>
#include <metadata.h>
#include <resultset_metadata.h>
#include <exception.h>



int main()
{
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::PreparedStatement *prep_stmt;

    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance(); 
    con =   driver->connect("server", "user", "pass");

    /* Connect to the MySQL database */
    con->setSchema("MySchema");

    std::vector<std::string> SymbolList;
    std::string SQL = "SELECT `MyList`.`Symbol` FROM `MySchema`.`MasterList`;";     
    try
    {

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery(SQL);
        while(res->next()) //If object exists
        {
            std::string symbol =  res->getString("Symbol");     
            SymbolList.push_back(symbol);
            std::cout << symbol;    
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::string d = ex.what();
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}//end method
```

I am still confused by the error I am getting the code seems to work fine in debug mode but in release mode it gives this error out. Any suggestions on what I should try and what I might be doing wrong. I am using VS2010.I can also upload a small project that I created